# how connect my Pi to Internet through PPPoE connection?

Tags: raspbian, internet, ppp

i'm new to pi. I need to connect my raspi, 
for the first time to internet. As the PC i need to 
establish an pppoe link to my router as required from
 my internet service provider. I don't know what's package 
precisly required, i read something like
 i need libpcap0.8, ppp and pppoeconf package ,
Then, I move the files to the Pi with a USB drive and Install 
the packages like this:
my write:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /home/pi/Desktop/libpcap0.8_1.3.0-1_armhf.deb
```

respond :

```
(Reading database ... 77992 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to replace libpcap0.8:armhf 1.7.4-2 
(using .../libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement
 libpcap0.8:armhf ...
Setting up libpcap0.8:armhf (1.7.4-2) 
...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

my write

```
$    sudo    dpkg -i  /home/pi/Desktop/ppp_2.4.7-1+2_armhf.deb
```

respond :

```
(Reading database ... 77992 files and directories currently
 installed.)
Preparing to replace ppp 2.4.7-1+2 
(using .../ppp_2.4.7-1+2_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ppp 
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of 
ppp:
 ppp depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of 
libc6:armhf on system is 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u8.

dpkg: error processing
 ppp (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving 
unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 ppp
```

my write

```
$    sudo  dpkg -i  /home/pi/Desktop/pppoeconf_1.21_all.deb
```

respond :

```
(Reading database ... 77992 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to replace pppoeconf 1.21 (using ...
/Desktop/pppoeconf_1.21_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement 
pppoeconf ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration
 of pppoeconf:
 pppoeconf depends on ppp (>= 2.4.2+20040428-2) | 
pppoe (>= 3.0); however:
  Package ppp is not configured yet.

 Package pppoe is not installed.
 pppoeconf depends on ppp 
(>= 2.4.1.uus2-4); however:
  Package ppp is not configured yet
.
 pppoeconf depends on ifupdown (>= 0.7.44~); however:

 Version of ifupdown on system is 0.7.8.
 pppoeconf depends 
on iproute2; however:
  Package iproute2 is not installed.

dpkg:
 error processing pppoeconf (--install):
 dependency problems 
- leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing
 triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for 
menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pppoeconf
```

and then run

```
sudo pppoeconf -eth0
```

and set my username and password of my internet service provider 
and after it get below respond:

```
pppoe-discovery: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by pppoe-discovery)


pppoe-discovery: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by pppoe-discovery)

/usr/sbin/pppd: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version
 `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /usr/sbin/pppd)
```

what is wrong ? please suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

For me to connect to the internet, I simply connected a Wi-Fi dongle and went to the settings and connected. I don't know if this will work on other pis besides 3.

Comment: The OP isn't using ethernet protocol.  See here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernethttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet